# How to fit buttons correctly in context to height of container

Tags: html, css, navigation

I'm been struggling with this problem for a couple of days now, i've tried to change every possible property in my CSS document, but none of them seemed to work.

site: http://www.mohrdevelopment.com

The problem is in the navigation bar.

1. problem: There is a spacing/gap between every button which i want to remove
2. Problem: All buttons (except Home button) expands to exceed the background of the navigation bar when hovered over. The height of navigation bar is 40px.

This is my HTML coding for the bar:

```
<div class="wrap">

        <ul class="navigation">
            <li class="current"><a href="index.html"><em class="home"/><b>Home</b></a></li>
            <li><a href="second.html"><em class="photos"/><b>Photos</b></a></li>
            <li><a href="projects.html"><em class="projects"/><b>Projects</b></a></li>
            <li><a href="about.html"><em class="about"/><b>About</b></a></li>
            <li><a href="contact.html"><em class="contact"/><b>Contact</b></a></li>
        </ul>
```

And this is my CSS code:

```css
body {
        font-family:sans-serif;
        background: url(images/background3.png);
    }

    .navigation {
        background:#1841c8 url(Navigation/Navigation/nav_background.png);
        height:40px;
        margin-bottom:0px;
        display:block;
        min-width:625px;
    }

    .navigation li{
        display:inline-block;
        line-height: 40px;
            }

    .navigation li a{
        color:#FFFFFF;
        padding: 11px 5px 15px;
    }

    .navigation li a em{
        height:32px;
        display:inline-block;
        padding: 0 5px 6px 50px;
        font-weight:bold;
        vertical-align: middle;
        background-position: 0 50%;
    }

    .navigation li a:hover{
        color:#00CCFF;
        background: url(Navigation/Navigation/nav_hover.png);
        text-decoration:none;
        padding: 11px 5px 10px;
    }

    .navigation .current a {
        color:#FFFFFF;
        background:url(Navigation/Navigation/nav_hover.png);
        padding-bottom:11px;
    }


    /*Navigation bar icons*/
    .navigation li a em.home {
        background-image: url(Navigation/Icon_images/home.png);
        background-repeat: no-repeat;

    }

    .navigation li a em.photos{
        background-image: url(Navigation/Icon_images/Photo.png);
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
    }


    .navigation li a em.projects{
        background-image: url(Navigation/Icon_images/projects.png);
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
    }


    .navigation li a em.about{
        background-image: url(Navigation/Icon_images/about.png);
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
    }

    .navigation li a em.contact{
        background-image: url(Navigation/Icon_images/Contact.png);
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
    }



    .wrap {
          margin:auto;
          width:80%;
          background:yellow;
        }
```

Hope someone can help me with this problem, i've spent hours troubleshooting it/looking for solutions.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem comes from the white-space between your `li` elements. I've answered a question to the same problem a few days ago. Take a look -> [Inline-Block without margins?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11459714/inline-block-without-margins/11461206#11461206)

Comment: Cheers, gonna try it out. I hate to find such a simple solution for it though, considering the countless hours i've spent to try to fix it :)

Comment: Tried your 2nd solution, updated my website with the results. Only made it worse :(

Comment: I'll take a look at your page, 1 sec

Comment: I' sorry, what solution have you tried? The 'font-size: 0' one or the other?

Comment: 'Font-size:0'. However i just figured i made a tiny mistake, made the div around the <ul> instead of the <li> seperately.. Didn't change anything except the width of the navigation bar though.

Comment: I see you're playing with it still. You're missing the "px" in the 'li's font-size.

Comment: How come? I'm seeing it correctly, when I change it, I think.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/14223/discussion-between-joplomacedo-and-jonas-pedersen)

Comment: Put it in the `.navigation li` - the font-size: 16px, that is. Don't forget the 'px' too. It should work.

Comment: A very possible problem might be that you're putting divs `inside` the `ul`. It's incorrect html, that actually gets some real problems getting rendered

Comment: Well, as i said. The first thing i tried, i put the div outside the ul - still same problem

Comment: Take a look at this fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/joplomacedo/B8UND/ - there are the basics you need.

Answer (score 0):

Fix gap between menu buttons

```
.navigation li a {
    color: #FFFFFF;
    display: block;
    padding: 2px 0 15px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

@Jonas Pedersen, have you tried using `float` property for the `li`?

I just checked your website, and did little tweak with firebug. here are the things I tried to change for your navigation CSS:

```
.navigation {
    background:#1841c8 url(Navigation/Navigation/nav_background.png);
    height:65px; /*add more height (was 40px)*/
    margin-bottom:0px;
    display:block;
    min-width:625px;
}

.navigation li{
    display:inline-block;
    line-height:40px;
    float:left; /*add 'float' property for the navigation menu*/
}

li {
    list-style: none outside none;
    margin-bottom: 20px; /* delete this property */
}
```

well, here's the recap:

1. Add more `height` for the `.navigation`
2. Add `float: left` for the `.navigation li`
3. Delete the `margin-bottom` from the `li` *{style.css : line 146}*

hopefully it helps you there...