# Responsive images and lists

Tags: css, responsive-design

Tryign to get it so that I have a max width for an image to be 308px and when the browser is scaled larger then the list will have more items per row. Just now it seems stuck at 3 list items per row but if I would like it to be fully reponsive and if the browser is scaled to minum it can be then it will be one image per row.

**html**

```
<ul>
    <li><img src="http://distilleryimage8.s3.amazonaws.com/23ddf3860e2911e29c2d22000a1e9e7e_6.jpg"></li>
    <li><img src="http://distilleryimage8.s3.amazonaws.com/23ddf3860e2911e29c2d22000a1e9e7e_6.jpg"></li>
    <li><img src="http://distilleryimage8.s3.amazonaws.com/23ddf3860e2911e29c2d22000a1e9e7e_6.jpg"></li>
    <li><img src="http://distilleryimage8.s3.amazonaws.com/23ddf3860e2911e29c2d22000a1e9e7e_6.jpg"></li>
    <li><img src="http://distilleryimage8.s3.amazonaws.com/23ddf3860e2911e29c2d22000a1e9e7e_6.jpg"></li>
    <li><img src="http://distilleryimage8.s3.amazonaws.com/23ddf3860e2911e29c2d22000a1e9e7e_6.jpg"></li>
    <li><img src="http://distilleryimage8.s3.amazonaws.com/23ddf3860e2911e29c2d22000a1e9e7e_6.jpg"></li>
    <li><img src="http://distilleryimage8.s3.amazonaws.com/23ddf3860e2911e29c2d22000a1e9e7e_6.jpg"></li>
    <li><img src="http://distilleryimage8.s3.amazonaws.com/23ddf3860e2911e29c2d22000a1e9e7e_6.jpg"></li>
    <li><img src="http://distilleryimage8.s3.amazonaws.com/23ddf3860e2911e29c2d22000a1e9e7e_6.jpg"></li>
    <li><img src="http://distilleryimage8.s3.amazonaws.com/23ddf3860e2911e29c2d22000a1e9e7e_6.jpg"></li>
    <li><img src="http://distilleryimage8.s3.amazonaws.com/23ddf3860e2911e29c2d22000a1e9e7e_6.jpg"></li>
    <li><img src="http://distilleryimage8.s3.amazonaws.com/23ddf3860e2911e29c2d22000a1e9e7e_6.jpg"></li>
    <li><img src="http://distilleryimage8.s3.amazonaws.com/23ddf3860e2911e29c2d22000a1e9e7e_6.jpg"></li>
    <li><img src="http://distilleryimage8.s3.amazonaws.com/23ddf3860e2911e29c2d22000a1e9e7e_6.jpg"></li>
</ul>
```

**css**

```
ul{
    position:relative;
    float:left;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    margin:45px 0 0;
}
ul li{
    width: 33.3333%;
    float:left;
}
ul li img{
    display: block;
    height: auto;
    width: 100%;
}
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/mynameisdonald/gfjDk/)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to use media queries.

Just set up media queries for each "breakpoint" and change the li width.

**For example:**

```
    /* Show one image on devices under 540px */
    @media screen and (max-width: 540px) { 
       ul li{
        width: 100%;
        float:left;
       }
    }

    /* Show three images on devices between 550 and 800px wide */  
    @media screen and (min-width: 540px) and (max-width: 800px) {
       ul li{
        width: 33.333%;
        float:left;
       }
    }

    /* Show five images on devices between 800px and 1180pxwide */  
    @media screen and (min-width: 800px) and (max-width: 1180px) {
       ul li{
        width: 20%;
        float:left;
       }
    }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/spacebeers/gfjDk/3/

Comment: Opted for the media-queries method. now my images scale pefectly! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use media queries (as per SpaceBeers' suggestion) coupled with a min-width property on the list items...
[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4tDfV/)

Answer (score 0):

Another idea would be to use `display: inline-block;` instead of `float: left` and set `max-width: 308px;` and `min-width: 100px;` for the list items.

## [*demo*](http://dabblet.com/gist/3835040)

**HTML**:

```
<ul>
    <li><img src="image.jpg"></li><!--
    --><li><img src="image.jpg"></li><!-- as many more list items as you need
    -->
</ul>
```

The way I've written it (with comments between list items) does serve a purpose - [any kind of whitespace matters when using `inline-block`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11459714/inline-block-without-margins).

**CSS**:

```
ul {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 45px 0 0;
}
ul li{
    min-width: 100px;
    width: 33.3333%;
    max-width: 308px; 
    display: inline-block;
}
ul li img{
    display: block;
    height: auto;
    width: 100%;
}
```